# UE4: Track the disappearance of actors in a scene

Tags: reference, null, unreal-engine4, unreal-blueprint

There are several Actors in the scene that are destroyed during the game. How do I track when this happens? TActorIterator keeps track of the Actors, but how to use it to keep track of their deaths and to issue a message about this? The idea is this: objects are created by the Spawner as a 2D array, destroyed, and if the iterator does not find them in the scene, a message appears. It's not flexible or fast, but first I want to understand how it should work conceptually.

```
for (TActorIterator<AObject> It(GetWorld()); It; ++It)
{

//if (Actors are not found)
{
// write a message
}

//but there is no message
//it is not clear what to compare with what

}
```

Comment: When you spawn the actor or at beginplay, bind a function to its `OnDestroyed` event.

Comment: Rotem thx very mach!

Comment: @Rotem That should actually be an answer and, if you can, please elaborate on the nature of Unreal's Event-based programming.